# Autowired field gives me null exception

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a class that uses a method from a bean.

I'm trying to inject that method into my class using `@Autowired`, but it gives me NullPointerException.

```
public class ChangePasswordServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        ChangePasswordService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsManager")
    private JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

    @Override
    public void changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) {

        // This is the line that throws NullPointerException, i.e., userDetails
        // Manager is not being injected by Spring
        userDetailsManager.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);

    }

}
```

My **xml** file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="securityDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="securityDataSource" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <qualifier value="userDetailsManager"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Why is this field not being filled? Am I missing something?

Comment: How is the `ChangePasswordServiceImpl` instantiated? How is it annotated?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. This class is the implementation of a RPC Service from GWT. Should it be annotated? I believe it's GWT who instantiates it.

Comment: You might want to look at [spring4gwt](http://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/) or some of the Spring/GWT tutorials, but yep, you're missing something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ChangePasswordServiceImpl` is not a Spring managed class (it is not in the xml configuration, therefore it is not a part of the `ApplicationContext`) `@Autowired` will do nothing for your class, which will cause you to get a `NullPointerException` when you try to use an instance of the class.

You should define a bean for `ChangePasswordServiceImpl` in your xml configuration, along with the rest that are currently there.

```
<bean id="changePasswordService" class="the.package.ChangePasswordServiceImpl"/>
```

Finally, you can then get a hold of it via the `ApplicationContext`.

```
//assuming you are holding onto an instance of the ApplicationContext
ChangePasswordServiceImpl service = appContext.getBean("changePasswordService", ChangePasswordServiceImpl.class);
service.changePassword("old", "new");
```

Comment: Hm, so Spring won't look for the `@Autowired` in all my classes, but just in those in the `ApplicationContext`. Since it's a GWT RPC Service Implementation class, and I don't instantiate it (GWT does it), I believe would be simpler to use a usual Servlet instead, right?

Comment: A bean does not need to be in the XML configuration to be Spring-managed, it can be annotated, which is why I asked that question.

Comment: Yes, it does not need to be in xml, but based on the information provided in the question, I assumed he was attempting to wire via xml exclusively.  @jdanielnd: I am not quite sure how gwt works, but if you have a web.xml deployment descriptor for your application, you can configure your application context in there.  Take a look at this link for more information on doing this:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-spring3/

Comment: I'm getting uncomfortable with it. What I want is just use a UserDetailsManager implementation from Spring Security. It has a change password method. I'm not very interested in keeping the application decoupled, or use Spring DI. However, as its implementation has beans in its fields, I can't figure out another way to access it's methods, and big changes in my project are becoming necessary. Isn't there any short-way to access its methods without getting so much into Spring DI?